# Optimize only certain chunks

Tags: webpack

I would like to optimize/mangle only vendor entry chunk ? how could i change the following webpack config to achieve that ?

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: ['./src/vendor.ts'],
        index: ['./src/index.ts'],
        home: ['./src/home.ts']
    },
...
    devtool: "source-map",
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.ejs',
            inject: 'body',
            hash: true,
            chunks: ['index']
        })
        , new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            mangle: true
        })
    ]
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to solve this using just one webpack config file.
Ended up splitting it into 2 webpack config files (first one optimizes  vendor.ts entry, and another one which just acts on index.ts and home.ts entry)